# origine dell'espressione "di punto in bianco"

Tags: idioms, etymology

Sono un'insegnante di inglese e spesso mi sento rivolgere dai miei studenti la domanda di come possono rendere delle espressioni italiane in inglese, mantenendo il significato originale. Per questa ragione sono perfettamente conscia del fatto che soltanto in pochi casi un'espressione viene resa in maniera quasi identica in lingue diverse.

Ciò premesso, sono però molto curiosa di capire come mai in italiano si usa l'espressione ***di punto in bianco*** per indicare qualcosa che accade inaspettatamente, senza che ci siano avvisaglie o motivi per prevederlo.

Non sono riuscita a trovare alcun riferimento alla sua etimologia nei dizionari che ho consultato. C'è qualcuno che mi può aiutare?

Comment: In English: "Point blank"

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_blank

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Una veloce ricerca su Google, mi ha portato [a questo risultato](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/lessico/lessico_063.html) sul sito della Treccani, da cui cito la spiegazione (in grassetto la parte più rilevante):

> Quando un'azione si svolge senza alcuna preparazione, producendo a volte anche un effetto di sorpresa, potremmo dire che è stata compiuta all'improvviso, di botto, di colpo, ex abrupto, improvvisamente o di punto in bianco (così di punto in bianco non saprei decidere; di punto in bianco si alzò e uscì). In questa accezione la locuzione avverbiale di punto in bianco viene usata figuratamente, appartenendo  il suo significato proprio al linguaggio militare e, in particolare, a quello della balistica. Nell'uso antico, infatti, **si indicava con l'espressione tiro di punto in bianco «il tiro di artiglieria senza elevazione, quando la linea di mira si teneva orizzontale, corrispondente nell'apparecchio di mira a una posizione zero, non contraddistinta da alcun numero (in bianco)**», come ben documenta un passo del Dialogo sopra i due massimi sistemi di Galilei: «non solo i tiri per le linee meridiane, ma né anco i fatti verso oriente o verso occidente riuscirebber giusti, ma gli orientali riuscirebbero alti, e gli occidentali bassi, tuttavolta che si tirasse di punto in bianco; perché sendo il viaggio della palla in amendue i tiri fatto per la tangente, cioè per una linea parallela all'orizonte, ed essendo che al moto diurno, quando sia della Terra, l'orizonte si va sempre abbassando verso levante ed alzandosi da ponente (che però ci appariscono le stelle orientali alzarsi, e le occidentali abbassarsi), adunque il bersaglio orientale s'andrebbe abbassando sotto il tiro, onde il tiro riuscirebbe alto, e l'alzamento del bersaglio occidentale renderebbe basso il tiro verso occidente.». E' interessante osservare che anche in francese esiste un'analoga espressione (de but en blanc), usata in entrambi i significati, proprio e figurato, per la quale il Grand Robert de la langue française  offre alcune varianti (de pointe en blanc, de blanc en blanc) e un ottimo esempio d'autore («écoutez, disait Mme Cottard, on est excusable de répondre un peu de travers quand on est interrogée ainsi de but en blanc, sans être prévenue», Proust, À la recherche du temps perdu).

Autore: *Massimo Migliucci*

Comment: molto interessante, non avevo mai pensato che "punto" potesse essere una forma verbale. Non sono una grande amante di Google come fonte di informazioni, per cui non avevo cercato nella Rete.

Comment: @Paola lieto di averti dato una mano a trovare ciò che cercavi. Non voglio fare il cool-kid ma ormai cercare su Google porta a molte più informazioni di quante puoi trovare in un dizionario cartaceo. L'importante è saper discriminare tra la robaccia e le informazioni autentiche ;)

Comment: @Gabriele: Per questioni contemporanee, soprattutto in ambito tecnologico e un po' nerd (non lo dico in senso spregiativo: ci rientro anch'io) ti do ragione; per questioni classiche, umanistiche, letterarie, non sempre (anche se in questo caso sì, grazie alla ricchezza del sito della Treccani).

Comment: @DaG sono nerd/geek e non ne faccio mistero (basta un click sul mio profilo ;) ), quindi rientro nella categoria di persone che *Se non c'è su Google non esiste* e ovviamente sono un po' biased. Chiaramente ci sono ancora informazioni racchiuse esclusivamente nella forma cartacea, ma sono sempre dell'idea che una ricerca su Google valga sempre la pena farla :)

Comment: resta da capire se è vero quanto scritto sulla Treccani, e cioè che il bianco stava per la posizione non contraddistinta da un numero, o quanto scritto su Wikipedia, e cioè che il bianco era il centro del bersaglio. Devo dire che in più occasioni ho trovato che a sbagliare era la Treccani, di cui, mi spiace dirlo, mi fido sempre meno. Aggiungo che _de but en blanc_ significa _dalla punta_ (del cannone o dell'arma da fuoco) _in bianco_.

Answer (score 8):

Il *Dizionario dei modi di dire della lingua italiana* di Carlo Lapucci (Garzanti-Vallardi, 1979) spiega che questa espressione «deriva dal linguaggio dell'artiglieria e una volta si usava per significare che il cannone veniva sparato con alzo uguale a zero, vale a dire senza nessuna elevazione, caso in cui l'indice del congegno di puntamento non segnava alcun valore (punto in bianco; francese: *de but en blanc*). Essendo la traiettoria orizzontale, il colpo, possibile solo a distanza ravvicinata, aveva il vantaggio d'essere improvviso e imprevedibile, dato che non richiedeva preparazione e calcoli preliminari» e lo collega a “sparare a zero”.

Comment: Vedi il mio commento alla risposta di Gabriele Petronella